# Less fundamental applications of Zeta regularization:

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sequences-and-series, zeta-functions, regularization

As we all know, zeta regularization is used in Quantum field theory and calculations regarding the Casimir effect.

> Are there less fundamental applications of zeta function regularization? By "less fundamental" I mean 
>   it 'naturally' pops up in more of an artificially / purely mathematically ideal constructed scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Zeta-function regularization of the determinant of the Laplacian, for example on a torus, might qualify as a "purely mathematical" application.
 See, for example, [On functional determinants of Laplacians in polygons and simplicial complexes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104271130) or [Zeta functions and regularized determinants on projective spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1181075478).

Answer (score 4):

Zeta function regularization computes the asymptotics of smoothed sums.

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/

Also, the regularized determinant of the Laplacian is related to the Ray-Singer analytic torsion, which is equal to the Reidemeister torsion:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_torsion